# How would I iterate through a list in SAS and translate / replace each piece with an imported mapping?

Tags: sql, dictionary, sas, mapping

I am new to SAS and I'm not sure how I would go about replacing each part of the dataset Have_1 with the translation data set (Have_2) that I imported into SAS.

```
 Data Have_1
    1111 1234 2222
    2938 3849
    1234 9388
    ...
    2222 2222


  Data Have_2
    1111 a
    1234 b
    2222 c
    2938 d
    3849 e
    ...
    9388 f

 Data Want
    a b c
    d e
    b f
    c c
```

Comment: Do you really need to convert them? Or do you just want them to print with  more user friendly descriptions?  If the latter then this looks like a perfect application for a FORMAT.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you want to replace them, this is what `proc format` does in SAS - maps a value to another value.

Here is how you might do that.  Note that you cannot reuse the original 3 variables (since they're numeric), but you could do a `rename` and `drop` combination if you really wanted the same variable names.

Using a `format` statement directly would also achieve the same result visually (but the underlying value is still the numeric one).

```
Data Have_1;
  infile datalines missover;
  input var1-var3;
datalines;
1111 1234 2222
2938 3849
1234 9388
2222 2222
;;;;
run;



Data Have_2;
  input numval charval $;
datalines;
1111 a
1234 b
2222 c
2938 d
3849 e
9388 f
;;;;
run;

data for_Fmt;
  set have_2;
  start=numval;
  label=charval; *could use rename for these but it makes the last bit more confusing to read;
  retain fmtname 'CHARVALF' type 'N';
  output;

  if _n_=1 then do;  *now define the 'other' value (hlo='o') for non-matched records;
    hlo='o';
    label=' ';
    call missing(start); *unnecessary but avoids duplicate start values and less confusing output;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;

data want;
  set have_1;
  format var1-var3 CHARVALF1.;   *option 1 - visual format only;
  array var[3];
  array varc[3] $;               *option 2 - new set of vars w/char vals;
  do _i = 1 to dim(Var);
    varc[_i] = put(var[_i],CHARVALF1.);
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hash method:

```
data want;
if 0 then set have_2;
if _n_=1 then do;
declare hash h(dataset:'have_2');
h.definekey('numval');
h.definedata('charval');
h.definedone();
end;
set have_1;
array var var:;
array new_var (3) $;
do i=1 to dim(var);
if h.find(key:var(i))=0 then new_var(i)=charval;
end;
keep new_var:;
run;
```